# ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' on Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, lxml, xml.etree

I am getting error while running "from lxml import tree" on python3.6

```
>>> import lxml
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'etree'
```

The same working on python3.4, I have tried many things to troubleshoot as below but didn't success.

```
python -m pip uninstall lxml
python -m pip install lxml==3.6.0

pip install -t /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages lxml==3.6.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiving 'ImportError: cannot import name etree' when using lxml in Python on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749916/receiving-importerror-cannot-import-name-etree-when-using-lxml-in-python-on-m)

Comment: The same visible at python but while import it getting same error

Answer (score 47):

Just in case anybody has similar issue. 
I also encountered this problem using Python3.6.
Just by uninstalling `lxml` and installing it again with `pip` the issue is resolved.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  Especially not in a lambda function environment.

Comment: I changed my lambda runtime from python3.8 to python3.6 and it magically worked

Comment: The system wide APT package was `python-lxml` , and the pip package was merely  `lxml` in my case.

Comment: `sudo pip3 uninstall lxml` and then `pip3 install lxml` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Got this working in Lambda with python 3.6

Turns out lxml wraps c libraries that are compiled for a certain processor architecture (I think)

Use precompiled binaries for lambda here: https://github.com/JFox/aws-lambda-lxml

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Python server with cPanel
Here are the commands I typed in the terminal to solve the issue:

```
pip uninstall lxml
pip install lxml
```

Afterwards I stopped and then started the Python server.

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows:**

After having the same problem at the instance of my Windows 2019 server, Python 3.8 and Anaconda, I downloaded the corresponding [whl package](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml), installed it with

```
pip install lxml-4.6.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64
```

It now works without problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when deploying an Azure python function using version 3.9.  I redeployed with 3.6 in Azure an everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same while running the code in VS code.For me I got it resolved by changing the interpreter in VS code from 32-bit to 64-bit.

Comment: I suspect the architecture was not the difference that matters hare and there is some other difference between those two interpreters' environments.