# Python Google Translator example

Tags: python, python-3.6, google-translate

I want to translate an English text like (final_str = 'Example') into German, does somebody have an example which I can build into my code and modify it?

Comment: There is a module called "translate", you can check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_text_processing/python_text_translation.htm#:~:text=Text%20translation%20from%20one%20language,provides%20translation%20for%20major%20languages.) out

Comment: @Praveen now I got an Error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'etree'`

Comment: Is there any other modules you are trying to import?

Comment: @Praveen no, I even tested it in a separate file and got the same error.

Comment: try it in console just the code i which is in the link, if you are getting the same error then, then try uninstaling and installing the module again

Comment: @Praveen in console everythink works fine, but in pycharm not, i don't get it, now i have two errors `ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\lxml\__init__.py)`

Comment: You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406638/importerror-cannot-import-name-etree-on-python-3-6) question, you have to just uninstall lxml and install it again, do it by using the command "pip uninstall lxml"

Comment: @Praveen it doesn´t work, but now googletrans workes. thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the module [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) you have a tutorial in the doc.
In your case a quick example would be:

```py
import googletrans

translator = googletrans.Translator()
translator.translate('Example', dest='de').text
```