# Getting the error since Python 3.9.5 was installed on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x

```
scrapy startproject dal
```

GIVES THIS ERROE SINCE I INSTALLES PYTHON 3.9.5 IN UBANTU 18.04

```
 from .. import etree
ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxml/__init__.py)
```

Comment: please don't yell

Comment: Possible related answer -  [ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' on Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406638/importerror-cannot-import-name-etree-on-python-3-6/53898728#53898728)