# What's wrong with the Investpy installation?

Tags: python, pip, python-import

One of my script is importing Investpy library and I encoutered the following error message when I have checked the site-package the Investpy is in place.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/LSH/WSFG_DEV/workspace/telegram_bot/roe_eps_check.py", line 9, in <module>
    import investpy
  File "/Users/LSH/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/investpy/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .stocks import get_stocks, get_stocks_list, get_stocks_dict, get_stock_countries, get_stock_recent_data, \
  File "/Users/LSH/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/investpy/stocks.py", line 16, in <module>
    from lxml.html import fromstring
  File "/Users/LSH/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .. import etree
ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' (/Users/LSH/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/lxml/__init__.py)
LSH@LSHs-Air workspace %
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? I have already remove and re-install Investpy but no luck.

Thank you everyone!! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' on Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406638/importerror-cannot-import-name-etree-on-python-3-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and do:

`pip install lxml-4.6.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64`

OR

`python -m pip install lxml==3.6.0`

If this doesn't fix the issue, uninstall lxml and reinstall it using `pip`

Source:

[ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' on Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406638/importerror-cannot-import-name-etree-on-python-3-6)

Comment: I am using MacOS, so the 1st command should not be used. the 2nd command has been tried, as I only got pip3 , pip will not work