# How to fix 'cannot import etree' error while executing rosrun "file

Tags: lxml, ros

I wanted to run a python file in which I imported Lxml, but I got this error although I installed the Lxml package:

ImportError: cannot import name 'etree'

Is there a way to fix this please?

Comment: What exactly was your `import` statement?

Comment: from lxml import etree

Comment: Take a look at this - it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749916/receiving-importerror-cannot-import-name-etree-when-using-lxml-in-python-on-m

Comment: @JackFleeting I changed the import statement to: from xml import etree and it worked but I am facing an other problem now, I can't import parse from xml.etree

Comment: What exactly is the error code now?

Comment: from xml.etree import parse
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse'